# How to plot many data sets by changing parameters on one plot in Python?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matplotlib, parameters

I am trying to find a set of parameters to fit some data. I want to be able to change the parameters and plot all the graphs on one plot. This is some simple example code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vel=10
r=2
array1=np.linspace(1,100,100)
array2=(array1**2)/(r*vel**2)
```

Now I can plot array2 vs array1. But I want to now vary my vel and r parameters and plot all those plots on one plot. For example I want to change it to r=3 and then vary vel from 1-10 and plot all 10 of those plots. Then change it to r=4 and vary vel from 1-10 and plot all 10 of those and so on all the way to r=10.

What is the most efficient way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Thats probably way too many lines. You could likely gain the same insight from a much smaller subset. But this will do what you asked.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
arr1 = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
for r in range(2, 11):
    for vel in range(1, 11):
        arr2 = (arr1 ** 2) / (r * vel ** 2)
        ax.plot(arr1, arr2)
plt.show()
```

You can get the same idea with fewer lines with the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
arr1 = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
for r in range(2, 11, 3):
    for vel in range(1, 11, 5):
        arr2 = (arr1 ** 2) / (r * vel ** 2)
        ax.plot(arr1, arr2)
plt.show()
```